# When I am trying to upload files, Why file is uploading three times in React

Tags: reactjs

I am working with React, When I am trying to upload file, I am cross checking uploaded file through in console can someone tell me why it is printing three times in console. please help me to resolve this bug. For designing I am using Ant designing. Please someone help me to resolve this bug

This is My code
This is App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Row, Col, Button, Modal, Upload, message, Divider, Table } from 'antd';
import { FilePdfOutlined, AudioOutlined, DeleteOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)

  const showPopUp = () => {
    setVisible(true)
  }

  const closePopUp = () => {
    setVisible(false)
  }

  const uploadFile = (file) => {
    const filesBasket = file
    console.log("fileBasket", filesBasket)
  }

  const columns = [
    {
      title: 'File',
      dataIndex: 'file',
    },
    {
      title: 'File Name',
      dataIndex: 'name',
    },
    {
      title: 'Actions',
      dataIndex: 'address',
    },
  ];


  return (
    <div>
      <Row>
        <Col span={24}>
          <Button onClick={() => showPopUp()} type="primary">Show PopUp</Button>
          <Modal
            visible={visible}
            onCancel={closePopUp}
            onOk={closePopUp}
          >
            <div className="main">
              <div style={{ marginLeft: "5px" }}>
                <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                  <Upload accept=".pdf" onChange={(e) => {
                    uploadFile(e.file)
                  }}>
                    <FilePdfOutlined style={{ fontSize: "25px", backgroundColor: "red", padding: "10px", borderRadius: "50%" }} />
                    <h6>Upload Pdf</h6>
                  </Upload>
                  <Upload accept="audio/*"
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      uploadFile(e.file)
                    }}
                  >
                    <AudioOutlined style={{ fontSize: "25px", backgroundColor: "red", padding: "10px", borderRadius: "50%", marginLeft: "25px" }} />
                    <h6 style={{ marginLeft: "25px" }}>Upload Pdf</h6>
                  </Upload>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <Divider />
            <Table columns={columns} size="small" />
          </Modal>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

This is App.css

````
.ant-modal-close-x > span {
  display: none;
}

.ant-upload-list {
  display: none;
}
```
If you have any questions please let me know, please help me to resolve this bug.
````

Comment: Does it happen on both uploads, or only in pdf or audio?

Comment: @JonasHendel Yes it happens on both uploads

Comment: try this: console.log(info.file.status), youll probably see something like, uploading, done

Comment: Please create code sandbox link of your problem

Comment: Hi @NishargShah Please check this https://7e0ot.csb.app/

Comment: its calling 3 times because the status are changing

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: Your file is not uploaded three times. It's because `onChange` of `Upload` in antd listens to any "change" of uploading files. It's fired during the uploading process, not when the uploading process is done.

If you look deeper into the log of `onChange` function, you will see that the logs are not the same: (see the `status`, `error`):
[image]

Comment: Hi @Trung Hieu Nguyen why it is showing error in status while uploading file is there anything wrong in my code please correct me.

Comment: I'm not sure because I'm not familiar with antd, but according to the official doc, you must have an uploading URL where you're gonna store your files.
https://ant.design/components/upload/#API (see action props).